# Redirecting output to a different window

Tags: shell, escaping, pipe, x11, xterm

In my script I want to open a new window to show the content of a variable. I have two half-baked ideas:

1. Something like `printf "%s\n" "$data" | xterm -e less` (does not work). Is it possible to redirect the output somehow, or do I have to use a temporary file?
2. Something like `xterm -e 'printf "%s\n" "'"$data"'" | less'`, but this leads to problems if `$data` contains something that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this equivalent example (added empty spaces, just to show the way the single quoted strings are get concatenated):

```
export data='embedded " double quote'
export data="$data embedded ' singlequote"
echo 'printf "%s\n" '  '"$data"'  ' | less'
```

results in:

```
printf "%s\n" "$data" | less
```

That is what xterm would see (just like echo above).

Comment: My example 2 will fail if $data has a `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xless`, `xmore`, or `xmessage`, depending on which you have installed.

Try any of these:

`printf "%s\n" "$data" | xless`

`printf "%s\n" "$data" | xmore /dev/stdin`

`printf "%s\n" "$data" | xmessage -file -`